# git workflow + preproduction

Tags: git, workflow, git-flow

Need some help with organizing branches and workflow.
Preconditions: 10 developers with git, 0 unit tests coverage, 10^5 lines of code.

In our repo with have `master` branch which acts as `production`.
Each feature is developed on a different branch, which also creates a new domain (`branch.qa.com`)

When It's done, QA team goes through the changes on the `branch.qa.com` and then it's merged into master and automatically pushed to production server.

**The problem**:
branch A could have `css` changes. It gets uploaded to `A.qa.com` and being checked.
Meanwhile the developer forks branch `B` from `master` and works on it, modifying the same `css`.

Both changes seems to be legit for their branches, but it may happen that change on `B` actually crushes something on `A`.

Merging `A` into `master` will be ok. Then merging `B` into `master` will have bad impact on the changes made by `A`.

**Ho do you rule out this situations? How do you incorporate `pre production`?**

Comment: recently switched to a [git rebase workflow](http://randyfay.com/content/rebase-workflow-git), seems to work well at work as it ensures that master is only ever fast-forwarded might be worth checking out.

Comment: Out of curiosity how do you manage "Each feature is developed on a different branch, which also creates a new domain" ?

Comment: @kursus, It was a while ago, but there was a hook on the git server, on commit it would run a script that adds a virtual host in an nginx config if not previously added, pull the code somewhere and point the server to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you follow git-flow, you have a separate `develop` branch, where all new features are branched out from and merged back into when done.

From the `develop` branch, you then create temporary `release` branches, that are tested (and possibly patched if necessary), and then merged into your `master`/`production` branch.

So the `develop` branch actually ends up as a kind of `pre production` branch.

If you then let your QA department handle the check of features before being merged back into `develop`, and all transitions to `release` and `master`, I presume you'd end up with what you want in your current department structure.

Diagram here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

As an added note, we are currently in the process of implementing git-flow together with code review through [gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/), which will give us a platform for handling all this - although in our case developers and QA team are the same people (although with an added [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) server with automated testing).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do you suggest moving a change from `develop` to `master` ? QA has finished their check on `branch.qa.com`, went to a developer and asked him to merge it into `develop`. Then they conduct another qa cycle on `develop.qa.com`. When they confirm, they go bother the developer again to merge `develop` into `master`.  
**Hard to automate**.

Comment: I could imagine using gerrit to allow QA to review and verify features before they are merged into `develop` - and then do the final test before merging a `release` branch into `master`? This should automate the process to some degree at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this link http://nxvl.blogspot.com/2012/07/a-continous-delivery-git-branching-model.html

I think in your organisation, the "`develop`" branch is missing.

pre production stage could be the "`develop`" branch and production is the "`master`" branch.

You can't directly merge in your "`master`" branch without further test due to possible conflict beetween branches (here conflict is not only 'git conflict' but also algorithm conflict)

Comment: Yep. That's exactly my problem.
So basically you suggest two QA sessions. First one is on the single independent feature branch, the second one is on the `develop` branch after the merge ?

Comment: two QA sessions is needed. First for you branch, to be sure everything is "ok" and a second one in "develop" branch where everything is merged to be sure you don't have any interactions beetween your branches.